# VIES Vat Control - Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have an error when I try this, always "Method not Allowed (405)"
I'm on Delphi 10.3

Have you an idee ? Thanks

My code seems good.

```
procedure TFEditCompte.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var TestVat : CheckVat ;
    RepVat : checkVatResponse ;
    WS : checkVatPortType ;
begin
  WS := GetcheckVatPortType ;

  TestVat := CheckVat.Create ;
  Try

  TestVat.countryCode := Copy( ETva.Text , 1 , 2 ) ;
  TestVat.vatNumber := Copy( Etva.Text, 3 , Length(ETva.text) -2 ) ;

  RepVat := WS.checkVat( TestVat ) ;

  if RepVat.valid then ShowMessage('Valid')
  else showmessage('Invalid' ) ;
  Finally
    TestVat.Free ;
    RepVat.Free ;

  End;


end;
```

Comment: There are some problems with your question, that make it practically unanswerable. What is `VIES Vat Control`? "Method not Allowed (405)", On which line? How are `CheckVat`, `checkVatResponse` and `checkVatPortType` defined? What is `ETva`? Please provide a [mre], of course including sufficient code that we can test it. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. When I imported the WSDL, there was an error inside.  The adress for the webservice had a "test" link.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the import of WSDL

```
function GetcheckVatPortType(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): checkVatPortType;
const
  defWSDL = 'https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatTestService.wsdl';
  defURL  = 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatTestService';
 // defURL  = 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/test-services/checkVatTestService' ;
  defSvc  = 'checkVatTestService';
  defPrt  = 'checkVatPort';
```

defURL wasn't good.